java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class com.example.demo.User in the delete end point
I am trying to implement an endpoint to delete a user and when I try to test the service via postman, the below error occurs.
{
    "timestamp": "2024-10-23T23:06:50.170+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "trace": "java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class com.example.demo.User (java.util.LinkedHashMap is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.example.demo.User is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader @13e92a05)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.ArrayList.removeIf(ArrayList.java:1755)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.ArrayList.removeIf(ArrayList.java:1743)\r\n\tat com.example.demo.UserService.deleteUser(UserService.java:71)\r\n\tat com.example.demo.UserController.deleteUser(UserController.java:40)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:255)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:188)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:926)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:831)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doDelete(FrameworkServlet.java:936)\r\n\tat jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:596)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)\r\n\tat jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:195)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:483)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:384)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:905)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)\r\n",
    "message": "class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class com.example.demo.User (java.util.LinkedHashMap is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.example.demo.User is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader @13e92a05)",
    "path": "/api/users/11"
}

My code looks like this.
UserController.java
@DeleteMapping("/{id}")
public void deleteUser(@PathVariable int id) throws IOException {
    userService.deleteUser(id);
}

UserService.java
public void deleteUser(int userId) throws IOException {
    List<User> users = getUsers();
    users.removeIf(user -> user.getUserId() == userId);
    saveUsers(users);
}

Stacktrace:
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class com.example.demo.User (java.util.LinkedHashMap is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.example.demo.User is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader @13e92a05)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.removeIf(ArrayList.java:1755)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.removeIf(ArrayList.java:1743)
at com.example.demo.UserService.deleteUser(UserService.java:71)
at com.example.demo.UserController.deleteUser(UserController.java:40)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:255)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:188)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:926)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:831)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doDelete(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:596)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:195)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:483)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:384)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:905)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)

Can please someone point out what I am missing?

I formatted the stack trace for you, but next time please take the time to do it yourself.

What type does getUsers() return? Which elements did you add (and how)?

The stack trace points that the problem is in getUsers(), please add it to your question.

My educated guess is that you have used raw types (List) and accidentally added a LinkedHashMap to your list. LinkedHashMap sounds like something that was JSON and then parsed with Jackson ObjectMapper, but without providing the target type (e.g. User).

This error says that in the getUsers() method you are actually returning not a list of User objects, but a list of LinkedHashMap objects, each of which, for example, can represent a set of fields of the User object obtained by selective selection SELECT id, name FROM users.
However, even if you fix this error, you will not get the desired result - deleting the user, since the users.removeIf() operation will only delete the user from the users list, but not from the database.
The canonical approach to solving the problem of deleting a user from the database is as follows. You need to load the required user from the database using the EntityManager object
User user = entityManager.find(User.class, id);

And then, after making sure that the user exists, delete it using the same EntityManager
if (user != null) {
  entityManager.remove(user);
}

If the user does not exist, then adhering to the REST style, you can send the client the 404 code.
For more information, see Hibernate User Guide.
If you are using Spring Data JPA and you don't need to strictly adhere to the REST style, then you can create a repository for the User entity
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
}

And then just use the UserRepository.deleteById() method
userRepository.deleteById(id);

For more information, see the Spring Data JPA User Guidle.
